# How does Linux kernel migrate the process among multiple cores?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler, multicore

**Context:**

Process-1 is executing on core-0. Core-1 is idle.

Now, process-1 uses `sched_setaffinity()` to change its CPU affinity as core-1.

**Question:**

Which kernel function(s) migrate the process-1 to execute on core-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the call sequence starting from the `sched_setaffinity` system call entry point in the kernel:

1. [sys_sched_setaffinity](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L4857).
2. [sched_setaffinity](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L4749).
3. [__set_cpus_allowed_ptr](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L1048).

In the last function, there are two cases as shown in the code at [line 1101](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L1101):

```
if (task_running(rq, p) || p->state == TASK_WAKING) {
    // ...
    stop_one_cpu(cpu_of(rq), migration_cpu_stop, &arg);
    // ...
} else if (task_on_rq_queued(p)) {
    rq = move_queued_task(rq, &rf, p, dest_cpu);
}
```

If the task to be migrated is currently running or waking up, then it is migrated by calling `stop_one_cpu`, which calls the following functions in order:

1. [migration_cpu_stop](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L961).
2. [__migrate_task](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L927).
3. [move_queued_task](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eda2d2dca830f0f8923b1f377d0fb70f576af1d/kernel/sched/core.c#L882).

The last function, `move_queued_task`, is the one that actually moves the task from the current runqueue to the target runqueue. Note that this is the same function that is called from the other branch of `__set_cpus_allowed_ptr`. That branch handles the case where the task is in any of the other states.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Hadi. I see how the process is moved to the runqueue of the core-1. However, I'm wondering how does the core-1 aware that there is a new task added to its queue and then execute this task?

Comment: @S.Wan It is the scheduler that takes care of that. It is invoked at every timer tick on every core and checks whether the current process running on the local core is the swapper process (the idle process). If it is, it will check whether the runqueue of the local core contains any runnable processes besides the swapper. If it does, it will schedule another process from the runqueue to run on the core instead of the swapper.