# How does Linux kernel automatically migrate threads (to balance load or otherwise)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, multicore

I looked at this Q&A [How does Linux kernel migrate the process among multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707124/how-does-linux-kernel-migrate-the-process-among-multiple-cores)
and I guess it's somewhat clear how the tasks are migrated to different cores via `sched_setaffinity()`

But I am right that the scheduler may decide to migrate a given task to some core at any tick?

I looked here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/kernel/sched/core.c and I don't see where something like `stop_one_core` is called from

It's called by `sched_exec` but that is... for exec syscalls only, right?..

It's also called by `migrate_task_to` but that's under an ifdef for NUMA...

So where's the usual scheduler migration path? Or am I wrong and such usual periodic migration is not performed by the scheduler but... by migration threads (`[migration/X]`) maybe?

Comment: Look for set_task_cpu in the scheduler.  Deadline calls it in 3 places.  I believe that if a task was blocked, it can be migrated when it is restarted, since its cache will be cold.

Comment: Note that scheduling is a distributed algorithm; any core looking for what to do next will call `schedule()`.  If there's a task that's ready to run, and isn't already running on another CPU, it might decide to run it on this core.  There are some heuristics to stop that from happening too often (e.g. if the task was recently running on another core, caches will be hot there).  Affinity is a way for user-space to limit the kernel's options for where to schedule a task.